# Laravel routing many layer deep subdirectories

Tags: laravel, routes

Im trying to convert an existing php site to Laravel.
The old php has one script running for any multiple layer sub-directory of an URL.

For example:

```
/foods/fruits/
/foods/fruits/apples/
/foods/fruits/apples/granny_smith
```

Are all managed by one script, which make sense as they are all pulling from the same hierarchical database table and the logic is the same.

But I don't see a way to do this using Laravel routing.
Is this possible with Laravel?

Comment: You can declare routes using `/foods/fruits/`, `/foods/fruits/apples/granny_smith` and so on, each route needs a handler. Check more on [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: That would require thousand of routes

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Sounds confusing.

Comment: My mistake, there would only be a few routes /{slug1}/,  /{slug1}/{slug2}/,  /{slug1}/{slug2}/{slug3}/, etc.  But this would limit the routing to a specific count of directory levels.  I'll use the answer I gave below instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
Route::get('fooditem/{food}', 'FoodCategoryController@show')
->where('food', '[a-z\_\/]+');
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [`Route::group()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-groups):

```
//Note: 'middleware' and 'as' are optional.
Route::group(['prefix' => 'foods/fruits', 'middleware' => ['jwt.auth'], 'as' => 'fruits.'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'apples', 'as' => 'apples.'], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'list', 'uses' => 'FruitsController@index']);
        Route::get('{type}', ['as' => 'show', 'uses' => 'FruitsController@show']);
    });
});
```

`$ php artisan route:list`

```
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                   | Name                            | Action                                                                      | Middleware                                   |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | foods/fruits/apples                   | fruits.apples.list              | App\Http\Controllers\FruitsController@index                                 | jwt.auth                                     |
|        | GET|HEAD | foods/fruits/apples/{type}            | fruits.apples.show              | App\Http\Controllers\FruitsController@show                                  | jwt.auth                                     |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```